# Proving $\phi$ is surjective if and only if $\tilde{\phi}$ is surjective.

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

As some background on notation, I am going to write down a theorem I've already proved.

> Let $X$ be a set with an equivalence relation $\sim$. Let $\phi: X \to Y$ be a map of sets such that $x_1 \sim x_2$ implies $\phi(x_1) = \phi
> (x_2)$, and $\pi: X \to X/\sim$ the canonical quotient map sending $x \mapsto \overline{x}$, where $\overline{x}$ is the coset containing $x$. Then there exists a uniquely defined map $\tilde{\phi}: X/\sim \to Y$ such that $\phi = \tilde{\phi} \circ \pi$.

The map is defined as follows. Given $y \in X/\sim$, the map $\pi$ is surjective, so there exists $x \in X$ such that $\pi(x) = y$. Then define $\tilde{\phi}(y) = \phi(x)$. I proved that this map is well-defined, unique, and works as intended.

The result I am trying to prove is:

> Prove that $\tilde{\phi}$ is surjective if and only if $\phi$ is surjective.

Here is my attempt.

> Suppose that $\phi$ is surjective, so given $y \in Y$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $\phi(x) = y$. Then
> $$
> y = \phi(x) = (\tilde{\phi} \circ \pi)(x) = \tilde{\phi}(\pi(x)), 
> $$
> where $\pi(x) \in X /\sim$. So $\tilde{\phi}$ is surjective.
>
> Conversely, suppose that $\tilde{\phi}$ is surjective. Given $y \in Y$, there exists $z \in X/\sim$ such that $\tilde{\phi}(z) = y$. As $\pi$ is surjective, there exists $x \in X$ such that $\pi(x) = z$. So
> $$
> y = \tilde{\phi}(z) = \tilde{\phi}(\pi(x)) = (\tilde{\phi} \circ \pi)(x) = \phi(x),
> $$
> so $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Not sure this is clear. How could $\pi (x_1)=\phi(x_2)$ when the left hand is an equivalence class in $X$ and the right hand is an element of some other set $Y$?

Comment: @lulu Sorry, this is a typo. Both should be $\pi$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I believe I've fixed it.

Comment: And why should $\pi$ be surjective?  All I see is that it takes equivalence classes to equivalence classes.  I can see where it must be injective (as a map on equivalence classes), but surjective?  Suppose $X=\mathbb Z$ with equality as $\sim$.  Then let $\pi(n)=2n$.

Comment: Isn't $\pi$ just the canonical quotient map? So given $[x] \in X/\sim$, we have $\pi(x) = [x]$. I hope I didn't make a mistake in defining things.

Comment: You did not define $\pi$ that way.

Comment: I think your post needs more consideration.  Maybe a good idea to take it down while you edit it for clarity and accuracy?

Comment: Yes, I will do that.

Comment: @lulu I believe it's correct now. Very sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, now I agree that it makes sense (+1).  And I agree with your arguments.  Note that the diagram made by your three functions, $\phi, \tilde \phi, \pi$ commutes, so all you are doing here is chasing points round that commuting triangle, and that is exactly what your arguments reflect.